# Azure managed instance connecting using ssh tunnelling

Tags: java, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I am connecting to the Azure SQL managed instance using PUBLIC ENDPOINT by JDBC connection. It is connecting properly. I can able to read the data using JDBC.

But If I tried to connect the public endpoint of azure sql using SSH tunneling, I am getting the below for the same database, username and password.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'xxx@xxxx'. ClientConnectionId:afa7f609-ffa0-4f46-af76-6e908d02d05c
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:108)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4290)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3157)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:82)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3121)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Even in network security group, I enabled all the port. Can anyone help me regarding this?